# Syntaxnet POS tagger use of capitalization

Tags: nlp, named-entity-recognition, syntaxnet, part-of-speech, parsey-mcparseface

I want to use Syntaxnet for getting the POS tags of tweets (and more specifically, extracting named entities from the text). However, Parsey McParseface is case-sensitive by default. Since tweets often not use capitalization, I was thinking of using a case-less tagger. I found something about capitalization in the code, but I was not sure if and how to use it:

https://github.com/dsindex/syntaxnet/blob/15831789a706cbc482efeeec635a8f0315d0b3fb/English/context.pbtxt

Let me give an example to be more clear. Consider the example sentences `John gave the money to Maria` and `john gave the money to maria` (with case and without case):

With caps:

```
gave VBD ROOT
 +-- John NNP nsubj
 +-- money NN dobj
 |   +-- the DT det
 +-- to IN prep
     +-- Maria NNP pobj
```

Without caps:

```
gave VBD ROOT
 +-- john NNP nsubj
 +-- money NN dobj
 |   +-- the DT det
 +-- to TO prep
     +-- maria NN pobj
```

As you can see, Maria is a NNP, whereas maria (without caps) is NN. When extracting named entities, it makes a difference if a word is tagged as NN or as NNP.

Is there a way to improve this? Is there a case-less Parsey McParseface for Syntaxnet?